# Why is Group By used in SQL join statements whereas Order By is used in sub queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was watching a T-SQL tutorial of converting subqueries to JOIN statements to achieve the same result. One of the things that the instructor does is replace the ORDER BY clause in the subquery statement to GROUP BY clause. I searched for the reason for doing this but could not find anything

**Edit**
Sub query

```
Select Name,
(Select SUM(QunatitySold) from tblproductSales where ProductId=tblProducts.Id) as QtySold
from tblProducts
order by Name
```

Join

```
Select Name, SUM(QuantitySold) as QtySold
from tblProducts
left join tblProductSales
on tblProducts.Id= tblProductSales.ProductId
Group by Name
```

These two produce the same result. Why can I not do Group By or Order By in both?

Comment: Please show us some code here.  Your current question is unclear.

Comment: `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` serve entirely different purposes. As it stands your question is unclear. Please illustrate your question with an example so we can understand exactly what you are asking.

Comment: It seems unlikely that your guy would have had ORDER BY in a subquery; sqlserver doesn't allow it (except in some narrow cases)

Comment: GROUP BY and ORDER BY are two really different things.ORDER BY allows you to sort the result set according to different criteria, such as first sort by name from a-z, then sort by the price highest to lowest. GROUP BY will aggregate records by the specified columns which allows you to perform aggregation functions on non-grouped columns (such as SUM, COUNT, AVG, etc).            If  instructor replace the ORDER BY clause in the subquery statement to GROUP BY clause then he must need some aggregated data.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: The second query may *happen* to provide the same answer at the moment, but that is not guaranteed to remain true, since you have not included an `order by` clause. So at some point in future, SQL may decide a different way of retrieving the data causing the 2 queries to return different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, when you aggregate columns (such as with sum, count, avg, and so on) you will want to put in a 'group by' statement so that you can aggregate for each grouping.  In the second query above, you want the quantity sold for each product 'name'.  For the purpose, the second query is the better form.

If you want the aggregation of the entire dataset, then you omit the 'group by' clause.  The first query above avoids the need for a group by clause in the subquery because the 'entire dataset' of the subquery is a result set already filtered by 'name'.  But it's more straightforward (and probably much more performant) to just use the 'group by' in the main query instead of creating a subquery.

The 'order by' clause has nothing to do with the 'group by' clause and is not it's replacement in any circumstance.  In fact, assuming ordering was necessary in the first place, the instructor was wrong to omit it.  He may have done so because the grouping procedure produced a result set that happened to return in order of name.  But this is not guaranteed and grouping should not be relied on to fix order.

But check out the video again.  It is very plausible that the instructor omitted it on purpose, but for a different reason.  I've inherited the work of developers who've loved subqueries.  They also tend to overuse orderings (and under-use it in other cases, such as omitting it in a 'top' query).  It is usually best to handle orderings in the business or the presentation layer of an application.  Your instructor may have made a quick statement to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

In your second query, Instructor uses  `SUM(QuantitySold)` which is aggregation over your table.

`SELECT  SUM(QuantitySold) FROM Table1` does not need `Group By` operator since it does not have grouping seperator column. where as

`SELECT Name, SUM(QuantitySold) FROM Table1` needs `Group by` because sum of `QuantitySold` will be grouped by name.

`Order by` can be used together with `Group by` and it is just for ordering your output.

I hope it is clear for you.